Why is Kafka consumer not working with existing groupid?
I'm working with Kafka consumers using Golang. Previously there is a consumer codebase which is running on server with consumer group consumer-1 and in that consumer there is so many data that it is reading working fine. But now I'm making and new consumer with the same group id with some tweaks below configuration but it's not receiving the messages.
Code base
  reader := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
            Brokers:          []string{config.KAFKA.Broker},
            Topic:            newTopic,
            MaxBytes:         10485760,
            GroupID:          "consumer-1",
            MaxWait:          time.Duration(2 * time.Second),
            ReadBatchTimeout: time.Duration(2 * time.Second),
            QueueCapacity:    10000,
            // Dialer:           dailer,
        })

Library I'm using
"github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"

This is above configuration that I did in previous code this is same. Why is this not working?

Does it work when this client is the only customer? How many partitions does the topic have? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

@eik there is only one partition that is default 0 . If the old consumer is running its working fine but when I stop the old one and start new consumer code with same groupid then it's not consuming. Example is same the code which I provided both of the consumer are made from it.

In order to have multiple consumers in the same group consuming from a single topic, you'll need to scale partitions on your topic.  In your case, scaling to 2.
1 partition means only one consumer at a time will be reading from that topic.
CAUTION: You can only scale up partitions.  Scaling down to a single partition will require deleting and recreating the topic.
